# How to read vertex coordinates and triangle index from an IndexedGeometryArray in Java3D?

Tags: java, opengl

I am doing mesh storing job now, i.e., briefly, convert an unindexed mesh to an indexed mesh.Works like this:

```
GeometryInfo gi = new GeometryInfo(GeometryInfo.POLYGON_ARRAY);
gi.setCoordinates(points);
gi.setStripCounts(strips);
gi.setContourCounts(contours);
gi.convertToIndexedTriangles();
IndexedGeometryArray ga = gi.getIndexedGeometryArray(true);
```

I guess that now it is a good time to read and store vertices and triangles information, which is expected in a form of `[[xyz],[xyz],,,[xyz]] as vertices` and `[[abc],[abc],[abc],,,[abc]] as triangles`, while number of this new vertices should be much less than the unindexed one.

However, the more `javadoc` I read, the more confused I was. It seems that method `getCoordinates()` inherited from GeometryArray will result the old vertices and new method of `getCoordinateIndices()` is very hard to understand like `getCoordinateIndices(0, indices)`. why 0? what had stored in this indices? If both of them were wrong, then which methods should apply?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After minutes, I figured it out something like this:

```
GeometryInfo gi = new GeometryInfo(GeometryInfo.POLYGON_ARRAY);
gi.setCoordinates(points);
gi.setStripCounts(strips);
gi.setContourCounts(contours);
gi.convertToIndexedTriangles();
IndexedGeometryArray ga = gi.getIndexedGeometryArray(true);

double [] originalVertices = new double [ga.getVertexCount() * 3];
for(int i = 0; i < ga.getVertexCount(); i++ ){
   double [] coord = new double [3];
   ga.getCoordinate(i, coord);
   for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      originalVertices[i*3+j] = coord[j];
   }//next i
}//next
int[] triangles = new int[ga.getValidIndexCount()];
ga.getCoordinateIndices(0, triangles);
```

I don't quite understand why but it works somehow, pretty well actually.